# Load a csv file python jupyter

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and I got this error I couldn't solve

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 url = 'http://localhost:8888/edit/Downloads/untitled.cvs'
 food2014_recalls = pd.read_csv(url)
```

This is my csv file:

animal,uniq_id,water_need
elephant,1001,500
elephant,1002,600
elephant,1003,550

I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can read cvs file in python panda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030806/i-can-read-cvs-file-in-python-panda)

Comment: Should be closed. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030806/i-can-read-cvs-file-in-python-panda. Plus `ParseError ... in line 12` while the author does only supply the first 4 lines of code.

Comment: @daniel451 I think the message is complaining about line 12 of the data, not line 12 of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import io
import requests
url ='http://localhost:8888/edit/Downloads/untitled.cvs'
res =requests.get(url).content      
food2014_recalls =pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.decode('utf-8')), error_bad_lines=False, comment='#', sep=',')
```

Comment: No, I got this error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-f04e706de6f6> in <module>
      3 import io
      4 url ='http://localhost:8888/edit/Downloads/untitled.cvs'
----> 5 res =requests.get(url).content
      6 food2014_recalls =pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.decode('utf-8')))

NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

Comment: i have updated the code, just import requests and if requests module is not installed please intall it by pip install requests

Comment: pd.read_csv(url,error_bad_lines=False)         just add error_bad_lines=False then try

Comment: I got this error : b'Skipping line 12: expected 1 fields, saw 2\nSkipping line 29: expected 1 fields

Comment: pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE) try it if error not resolved then edit your question with your csv file, not entire file but some rows so that i can try with your file.

Comment: I did update the question with few rows of csv file

Comment: i updated my code, if error not resolved then see in line number 12 in your csv i think there is somthing that pandas can't parse.

Comment: I only have 9 lines

Comment: I got this error: ---> 10 food2014_recalls =pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(res.decode('utf-8')), error_bad_lines=False,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE , comment='#', sep=',')

NameError: name 'csv' is not defined

Comment: remove this quoting = csv. ..        upload your file to google cloud send the link if error not resolved